# Django: Send current logged in user as JSON

Tags: json, django, api

I would like to create a GET endpoint that returns the `JSONResponse` of the current logged-in user. Ideally, it would look like:

```json
{
    "username": "joe",
    "email": "joe@plainviewhcp.com",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "last_login": "2021-09-17T17:11:00.039Z",
    "is_superuser": true,
    "is_active": true
}
```

(Note that I'm using Django 3.2, not Django REST API)

This requires serializing the current user object, but serializing a single object is... *opaque* in the documentation, and many similar questions have responses from 6 or more years/two major versions ago.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by re-querying the user from the `request.user` object and singling out the first field. This has the added benefit of controlling the fields. Note that I've already tested to make sure the user is logged in at this point.

```py
def api_current_user(request: HttpRequest):
    user = (
        User.objects.filter(pk=request.user.pk)
        .values(
            "username",
            "email",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "last_login",
            "is_superuser",
            "is_active",
        )
        .first()
    )
    return JsonResponse(user)
```

Comment: You are a life saver. Damn I have been searching for about two hours now just seeing irrelevant stuff like serializing. I was just about getting frustrated. Thank you very much for this.